# Dealing with network errors in Chrome + Backbone

Tags: ajax, error-handling, console, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple backend - Php RESTful API

When data is not available for specific parameters (for instance, a date and company_id) - we return an error (say 401) along with a message

In Backbone, I am then able to deal with the error / success of requests with:

```
data = {date:"2013-01-01",company_id:"500"}
model.fetch({data:data})
  .success( ()=> @dealWithSuccess )
  .error( ()=> @dealWithError )
```

This is fine but in the console I get notifications on network failures for the GET and OPTIONS requests

How can I have them not show up in the console? as I don't want clients to see this

Comment: What `console` do you mean? Backbone has no display error flag.

Comment: - chrome console, I assume its the same for any browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [Status code `401`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is a valid [**RFC 2616 error**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

The default [Google Chrome console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console?hl=de#errors_and_warnings) output is mixed with your own app debugging output and is viewable by anyone who knows the console.

Chrome displays valid RFC errors as red colored messages:

[image: GOogle Chrome console example output]

You could *change* the response code to a non RFC status code (like `999`) to get rid off the coloration.

This has nothing to do with an `XMLHttpRequest Object` malfunction.

Comment: What would be your suggestion given my specific situation? Leave it since clients won't be viewing the console or change my status codes?

Comment: @imrane The [rfc2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) s only a recommendation. Feel free to change the status codes. Remember: The console is a tool *for developers* and the red color is a indicator for you, that something was going wrong. As long it's not a critical application or server error, **do not worry**.